# Numerical methods, approximation in the sense of the least squares to find Polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, least-squares

Given these table of points `x = [-1 -1/2 0 1/2 1]` and `f(x) = [2 1 0 1 2]`. Find the approximation polynomial in the sense of the least square with weight function $w(x) = 1.$

My attempt:

So we take the canonical base $1, x, x^2$ and thus we have the polynomial:

$$P(x) = c_0 + c_1x+c_2x^2$$

Our goal is to find $c_0, c_1, c_2$.

We write the system:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}c_0<1, 1>+c_1 <1, x> + c_2 <1, x^2>= <1, f>\\c_0<x,1>+c_1<x,x>+c_2<x,x^2>=<x,f>\\c_0<x^2,1>+c_1<x^2,x> +c_2<x^2,x^2>=<x^2,f>\end{array}\right.$$

Now we just calculate all the scalar products and find $c_0,c_1,c_2.$ My question is: how do I calculate the scalar product between 2 functions with discontinuous points? Do I just sum up the values of $x$ or $f$?And why is that? What is the intuition behind that?

Comment: Because of the symmetry of the data and weight function, the result has to be an even function. So you can set $c_1=0$ from the start, simplifying the system. And yes, $\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^5 w(x_k)f(x_k)g(x_k)$, there is nothing more thinkable with the given information.

Comment: @LutzL The question actually is how to calculate the scalar product between those functions on discontinuos points? Summing up the values? And why is that? Also what if the weight function was something else what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the scalar product $$\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^5 w(x_k)f(x_k)g(x_k)$$ on the sample space gives the linear system
$$
\pmatrix{5&0&2.5\\0&2.5&0\\2.5&0&2.125}
\pmatrix{c_0\\c_1\\c_2}
=
\pmatrix{6\\0\\4.5}
$$
leading to $c_1=0$. Eliminating $c_0$ gives $1.75c_2=3\implies c_2=\frac{12}7=1.7142857..$ and lastly $5c_0=6-\frac{30}7=\frac{12}7\implies c_0=\frac{12}{35}=0.342857..$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to make this system too hard. There is a much more easy way to solve the least squares. I hope this answer is also applicable to your problem, since I'm not following your system. At least the final polynomial is in this answer, so that can be seen as a hint or a direction.

The least squares formula is given by minimizing 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n y_i - f(x_i,\beta)
\end{equation}
which can be done by differentation and solving for 0, which yields, in matrix form, the matrix of coefficients $c$:
\begin{equation}
c = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty
\end{equation}
I assume you are familiar with this. Now, let's see how to solve this numerically. I programmed it in R, but I hope you can see how to write this program in any langauge.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

Non_Lin_Regressie <- function(x,y){
  # Solving the least squares method
  Pol_Matrix          <-    matrix(c(x^2,x,rep(1,length(x))),ncol=3)
  LHS_pol             <-    t(Pol_Matrix) %*% Pol_Matrix            # Computes the LHS
  RHS_pol             <-    t(Pol_Matrix) %*% y                     # Computes the RHS
  x_sol_pol           <-    solve(LHS_pol,RHS_pol)                  # Solves the equation
  return(x_sol_pol)
}

x <- c(-1,-1/2,0,1/2,1)
y<- c(2,1,0,1,2)
sol <- Non_Lin_Regressie(x,y)
func <- sol[1]*x^2 + sol[2]*x+sol[3]
plot_ly(x=~x, mode= 'lines') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~func, line = list(shape = "spline"), name= 'solved by LS') %>%
  add_trace(y=~y, name= 'normal plot')
```

Which yields the following coefficients matrix

```
          [,1]
[1,] 1.7142857
[2,] 0.0000000
[3,] 0.3428571
```

And hence the following polynomial
\begin{equation}
1.71x^2+0.34
\end{equation}
We can also plot both the given data and our fitted polynomial

[image]

Comment: The question actually is how to calculate the scalar product between those functions on discontinuos points? Summing up the values? And why is that? Also what if the weight function was something else what should I do?